# How many Java Strings Created?

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String [] args){ 
    String s = "java"; //line 1
    s.concat(" SE 6"); //line 2
    s.toLowerCase();  //line 3
    System.out.print(s); //line 4
 }
```

The answer to this question is "4". I thought it would be "3". My confusion is line 3, which creates "java" string again, but doesn't java know that the "java" string already exist in the string constant pool, so why create it again?

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java, so `s.toLowerCase()` returns a new String object.

Comment: @Ocracoke - Nope. He is not re-assigning the value returned by `concat`, so s will be "java" and then `"java",toLowerCase()` will return the same String "java"

Comment: @TheLostMind Ah, just looked at the code for `toLowerCase()` and seen that there is a `return this` line in it when it finds nothing to do. My bad.

Comment: @TheLostMind However, a new string _object_ will still be created. The string itself, OTOH, should have the same address in the constant pool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3 Java Strings are created.

```
1. "java"  -> Goes into String constants pool // will be added if no already present
2.  " SE 6" --> Goes into String constants pool?
3. java SE 6 --> Goes on heap (call to concat)// Note : You are not re-assinging the value returned from concat() So s will still be "java"
** toLowerCase() \\ does nothing in your case since "java" is already present. toLowerCase retruns the same "java" object ( as there is no modification required to turn it into lowercase)
```

Comment: Does the object returned in step 3 has references to both strings, so that is why it doesn't count as a string itself?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I meant the same thing. The same String will be returned as there are no uppercase chars in the string. Edited the answre to make it clearer. :)

Answer (score 5):

> Java know that the "java" string already exists in constant pool, so it needs not to create the object again?

Actually, it's not `"java"` string that exists in the pool, but `"Java"` (in uppercase). If it were indeed `"java"`, `toLowerCase()` would have recognized it, and returned the original string. But since the return value (i.e. `"java"` in all lowercase) does not match the original string (i.e. `"Java"` in mixed case) a new `String` object needs to be created, bringing the count to 4.

**Edit:** After the edit to the question the answer changes: now that you've changed `"Java"` to `"java"`, the number of objects that get created is three, because Java `String` has an optimization that returns the original string from `toLowerCase` when the string is already in lowercase. So line 1 creates one string object `"java"`, line 2 creates two string objects `" SE 6"` and `"java  SE 6"`, and lines 3 and 4 do not create any additional objects.

Comment: These are line numbers not how I counted the objects!